# How can i solve VBoxManage.exe: error: Format autodetect failed: VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: windows, command, virtual-machine

I am getting the following error when i tried to run this below. I have being trying to follow the instruction from this http://www.randallkent.com/virtual-box/change-uuid-of-virtualbox-vdi link.

I did the following.

```
 C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe internalcommands setvdiuuid "C:\Security"
```

And got this error below,

VBoxManage.exe: error: Format autodetect failed: VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

How can i solve the above error?

Answer (score 5):

You have to select the VirtualBox `.vdi` file with the `sethduuid` command.

```
 C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe internalcommands sethduuid "C:\Security\VirtualBox\my_vm\my_vm.vdi"
```

Also it should be `sethduuid` not `setvdiuuid`, but that may depend on your VirtualBox version. I am using 4.3.10

Answer (score 1):

As i was trying to attach existing VM, i had a problem with the error telling me it exist even thou it was my first time installing the file. I then tried to find the solution from online but it didn't work as it was me this error :VBoxManage.exe: error: Format autodetect failed: VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I then located where the VM it is installed and deleted all the files that exist.

```
 C:\Users\D409\.VirtualBox
```

Hope this will help others

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue; but I realised that I had to use the same UUID as the original, changing just one or two last bytes, and it worked.

Comment: From the answer, doesn't looks like it relates to the question being asked. You need to describe how it actually fixes the issue

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using `sethduuid`. Replacing my .vdi file in "C:/" directory worked for me. I guess it's because of cyrillic letters in the original path.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while resizing the VM

The solution was simple, just open the virtual box xml file on the below location

```
C:\Users\USER_NAME\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml
```

(Don't forget to replace your logged in user with the USER_NAME)

Then look for your VM under **MachineEntry** tag and use this PATH, or replace it, and save.

Then run your command with this path, It should work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether you added the correct path to Virtualbox .vdi file
   "C:\Security" - this is not the path to .vdi file

> ```
> C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe internalcommands 
>  setvdiuuid "C:\Security\win.vdi"
> ```

2. Run cmd as administrator

Answer (score 0):

1. coppy file to desktop name.vdi or *.ext
2. cd Desktop/
3. VBoxManage  internalcommands sethduuid name.vdi
   VboxManage is the index environment variable to * folder VboxManage
   With Macos which VboxManage
4. VBoxManage  internalcommands sethduuid name.vdi

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you added more detail. Can you tell us what you're trying to do?

Comment: I share the solution

Comment: That was odd there were no answers when I commented.. mobile app I guess?